# kubectl from ec2 to my EKS cluster fails because of i/o timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I have a EKS cluster and I want to work with kubectl from my bastion ec2 (both are in same VPC).
Belows are current settings for both of them.

EKS

- networking => Public and private
- and have some public access source allowlist

Bastion

- public subnet (also I tried another bastion server with private subnet.)
- with elastic IP

I tried `kubectl get nodes` from bastion but always fails because of i/o timeout.

Is there any way to work with my bastion server?

Comment: How are you configuring your kubectl context?

Comment: It just because of I didn't added ip address of bastion server to security group of eks cluster. After I add ip address, it did work ;)